# How can I solve 'memory leak' of Digikam 4.12 in Ubuntu 14.04 during maintenance?

Tags: 14.04, memory-leak, digikam

I wouldn't wanna miss Digikam:  it fulfills all my needs (and much more).

Unfortunately, I ran into some serious trouble, so that much functionality is lost:  during maintenance tasks, the program uses all available memory, and then stops working or disappears (without even a crash report).

Doing these tasks manually is still possible (for example adding tags to images, or updating thumbnails), but only album by album, and for say 2000 albums... that's a lot of work (and very time consuming)...

So does anyone have a sound solution?

From everything I find by searching, it's a known problem, regularly reported as 'solved'.  Unfortunately, not (yet) for me.  I'm no developer or programmer, so lots of what I read is undoable for me.  Please, if you have some instructions, be clear and very specific.

Thanks in advance for all possible help.

PS: I installed Digikam using [these Ubuntu Handbook instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/install-latest-digikam-4-12-ubuntu/)

Downgrading didn't work for me.